# Is there a way to create a google app script that exports an invoice as a pdf and then emails it as an alias?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have tried to create my own script and it runs without error but I don't receive any emails. I have set up an alias in my Gmail but nothing seems to work

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var filename = "Current Month " + ss.getName();
  var SendBook = ss.copy(filename);
  var me = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var aliases = GmailApp.getAliases();
  Logger.log(aliases);
  if (aliases.length > 0) {
    GmailApp.sendEmail('email@host.com','Subject', 'Body', {'from': aliases[0], attatchments: [SendBook.getBlob().setName(filename)]});
  } else {
    GmailApp.sendEmail(me, 'No aliases found', 'You have no aliases.');
  }
}
```

Any suggestions would really help

Comment: Is the issue on receiving the email? or on the attachment? If it's about the attachment, then I'm seeing a typo on your code. Use `attachments` instead of `attatchments`. If it's receiving the email, are you sure you have an alias? If you don't, you should be able to receive that email confirming that you don't have one. If you have, it is sent to `email@host.com`. Is the email used in `sendEmail` yours? Can you confirm whether the email was successfully sent to the address or not? Can you include the structure of your `aliases` variable? Was it blank? You specifically use the first element

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the aliases. You can debug which is actually causing the issue.

Comment: Update: The code does work, but for some reason was giving me errors on the one sheet. Seems to be good now.